# AWX Ansible - Dont read galaxy collections

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm using AWX ansible ver 20.0 with kubernetes

My playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Install 7zip with offline package chocolatey
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create folder
      win_file:
        path: 'C:/Instalki'
        state: directory

    - name: Copy installer
      become: true
      win_copy:
        src: "../playbooksWindows/installers/7zip.22.01.nupkg"
        dest: "C:/Instalki/7zip.22.01.nupkg"
        
    - name: install 7zip packages
      win_chocolatey:
        name: "7zip"
        state: present
        source: "C:/Instalki/7zip.22.01.nupkg"

    - name : clear folder
      win_file:
        path: "C:/Instalki/7zip.22.01.nupkg"
        state: absent
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:236: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
No config file found; using defaults
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'win_chocolatey'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to be in '/runner/project/playbooksWindows/Install_7zip.yml': line 27, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: install 7zip packages
      ^ here
```

My actual ansible collection on awx-ee container

```
# /usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection              Version
----------------------- -------
amazon.aws              4.1.0
ansible.posix           1.4.0
ansible.windows         1.11.1
awx.awx                 21.5.0
azure.azcollection      1.13.0
community.vmware        2.9.1
google.cloud            1.0.2
kubernetes.core         2.3.2
openstack.cloud         1.9.1
ovirt.ovirt             2.2.3
redhatinsights.insights 1.0.7
theforeman.foreman      3.6.0

# /home/runner/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection            Version
--------------------- -------
ansible.windows       1.11.1
chocolatey.chocolatey 1.3.0
```

I was installing collection with:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install chocolatey.chocolatey
```

Any ideas how to fix it on docker in ver AWX 17.01 everything works fine :/

Comment: Did you try with the full fqcn for the module => `chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey`?

Comment: Yes i've tried this
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'chocolatey.chocolatey.win_chocolatey'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.